How to convert a list with multiple rows into multiple columns
I'm trying to transpose a list consisting of 2 rows into multiple columns.
What I have
$`1`
    may  servic    busi    oper product 
     98      82      65      59      51 

$`2`
    health  care    serv    busi state 
     99      80      66      57      49 

$`3`
    compani  servic    busi    can market 
     96      76      65      58      50 

What I want
[,1]      [,2]      [,3]         [,4]         [,5]          [,6] [,7] [,8] [,9] [,10]
1  "may"     "servic"  "busi"       "oper"       "product"     98   82   65   59   51   
2  "health"     "care"  "serv"       "busi"       "state"     99   80   66   57   49   
3  "compani"     "servic"  "busi"       "can"       "market"     96   76   65   58   50   

Tried
list <- 
  do.call(rbind, lapply(top_5, function(x) 
    { x <- names(x); length(x) <- 5; x } ))


Could you please provide dput(your_list) result as it is not clear what is the strucure of your list's elements (what "a list consisting of 2 rows" mean)

You can combine the lists into a single dataframe and then convert it to the shape you need.
# Create a data frame from the list
df <- do.call(rbind, lapply(top_5, function(x) {
  as.data.frame(t(unlist(x)))
}))

# Add the column labels
labels <- c("may", "servic", "busi", "oper", "product")

# Create a new data frame with the labels as columns
result <- cbind(data.frame(t(labels)), df)


Thank you for your input. I might need to add one point that the "labels" are not fixed in my dataset. For instance, in the example I mentioned above they are "may", "servic", "busi", "oper", "product". However, in other lines they might be "vehicl", "may", "electr",  "energ", "model" or "health", "care", "busi", "servic",  "state" and so on. I also made changes to the example above to avoid misunderstanding.

So try this
# Dynamically extract the labels from the first sublist
labels <- names(top_5[[1]])

Assuming your desired output is a data.frame. If all named vectors in l are of the same length, try
l = list(`1` = c("may" = 98, "service" = 82), `2` = c("health" = 99, "care" = 80))
as.data.frame(do.call(rbind, lapply(l, \(x) c(names(x), unname(x)))))
# or 
as.data.frame(t(sapply(l, \(x) c(names(x), unname(x)))))


      V1      V2 V3 V4
1    may service 98 82
2 health    care 99 80

This is probably not the fastest or most compact solution.
